# How to test non idempotent Web Api endpoints with Specflow

Tags: api, bdd, specflow

I'm developing a Web API, which features some CRUD operations I want to test.

When running the following scenario the test is expected to pass always given the same parameters.

```
Scenario: Check each employee's info
Given an Employee's Id is <Id>
When getting the Employee's info
Then the First Name should be <FirstName> and the Last Name should be <LastName>

Examples:
  | Id | FirstName | LastName    |
  | 1  | George    | Georglou    |
  | 2  | John      | Johnopoulos |
  | 3  | Mike      | Mikou       |
```

On the other hand, when running the following scenario,

```
Scenario: Create a new Employee
Given an Employee's Fist Name is <FirstName> and Last name is <LastName>
When creating the Employee
Then the status code should be 201

Examples:
  | FirstName | LastName    |
  | Jack      | Jackglou    |
```

the test is passed only the first time because after that the employee is already created which is logical.

How do I test non idempotent endpoints? Do I need to change the example data each time I'm running the test? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

The general solution is to delete the test data after the test is completed. Unfortunately, there is no general code you can write to accomplish this.

The general process is:

1. Track the people that get created using the [ScenarioContext](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/ScenarioContext.html).

   ```cs
   [Binding]
   public class EmployeeSteps
   {
       private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

       private List<Guid> TestEmployees => (List<Guid>)scenario["TestEmployees"];

       public EmployeeSteps(ScenarioContext scenario)
       {
           this.scenario = scenario;
       }

       [Given(@"Given an Employee's First Name is ([^ ]+) and Last name is ([^ ]+)")]
       public void CreateEmployee(string firstName, string lastName)
       {
           var api = new YourAPI(); // <-- however you init your web API service
           var employeeId = api.CreateEmployee(/* pass whatever you need to here */);

           TestEmployees.Add(employeeId);
       }
   }
   ```
2. In an [AfterScenario hook](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Hooks.html), call API endpoints to delete the people that were created. Initialize this collection of "test employees" in a BeforeScenario hook:

   ```cs
   [Binding]
   public class Hooks
   {
       private readonly ScenarioContext scenario;

       public Hooks(ScenarioContext scenario)
       {
           this.scenario = scenario;
       }

       [BeforeScenario]
       public void CreateTestEmployeeCollection()
       {
           // Create list of employee Ids. Use whatever type for List<T>
           // that your API returns. This example uses a Guid. Could be
           // and int. Check your API documentation.
           scenario["TestEmployees"] = new List<Guid>();
       }

       [AfterScenario]
       public void DeleteTestEmployees()
       {
           var api = new YourAPI(); // <-- however you init your web API service
           var employeesToDelete = (List<Guid>)scenario["TestEmployees"];

           foreach (var employeeId in employeesToDelete)
           {
               api.DeleteEmployee(employeeId);
           }
       }
   }
   ```